# I need help nextjs styling

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I import component level module scss as

```
import styles from './SideDrawer.module.scss';
```

then apply the scss below

```
<div className={styles.container}></div>
```

However, the scss is not taking effect.

Note: If I use

```
import './SideDrawer.module.scss';
```

then apply the scss below and it works

```
<div className="container"></div>
```

next.config.js - shows built-in css is disabled

```
    const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
module.exports = withSass({
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        issuer: {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
        },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });
  
      return config;
    },
});
```

How can I make the first import style to work?

Comment: you should use `classname={styles.container}`

Comment: what's your version of next.js?

Comment: My bad. I already used

<div className={styles.container}></div>

But the styling is not taking effect.

next.js version is 10.0.5

Thank you and I look forward for more help.

Comment: I'd recommend using [Next.js built-in Sass support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support). And here's an example on how to use it: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-next-sass

Comment: Thank you. I revert to the Next.js built-in Sass. Painful after I have gone to some extent with the project.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation on the part of Next.js. Revert back to built-in Sass. Thank you all